# Badges appear halved

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On all posts and in question lists, but not in the top bar, the badges are misaligned.

[image]

For example, the CSS for `.badge3` has changed from `background-position: -62px -398px;` to `background-position: -60px -398px;` recently. Everything moved 2px to the right. As far as I can see, this only appears on Stack Overflow and its Meta.

---

Update: This appears to be fixed right now!

Comment: Badges now change with the phases of the moon. You're welcome

Comment: Might be a typo, because the badge width has been set to "6px", but it should be "8px".

Comment: @Tom: Nah, any width from 6 to 8 px is fine on SO.

Comment: Still i am facing this issue ??

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur I don’t. Try clearing your cache with `Ctrl` + `F5`.