# Badges not coming completely circular on SO and also on meta-SO posts

Tags: bug, design, badges

Why badges are not appearing completely circular even after I have deleted cache data of my browser (Chrome).

My Chromium Version is Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

[image]

Comment: Which badges? Why would they be circular and what does the cache data have to do with it? Maybe a screenshot would make things a bit clearer?

Comment: Can you please look at my updated post.

Comment: No repro on Chromium 60.

Comment: My Chromium version is Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: Wierd. On Chrome Versjon 61.0.3163.79 (32-bit) they're circular both on my own answers and on yours.

Comment: Are you running any kind of userscript that might interfer with the site's CSS?

Comment: No as far as i know, i am using some extensions like Hola

Comment: I've seen that happen a few weeks ago (right after MSE got the new top bar), but not since then.

Comment: related bug report: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356707/badges-appear-halved

Comment: Maybe a resolution problem ? what resolution are you using  ? (supposing you're in full windows, otherwise you'd need to tell us the size of your chrome windows).

Comment: chrome resolution is 100 %, not in full window, and my windows resolution is 1920 * 1080, `actually in my windows defuault config is 125 % that's why this was happening changing it to 100 % circles are coming fully` but the thing is 100 % is to small can't it work on 125 % configuration.

Comment: It is getting clipped, one pixel more and it would have looked a lot better.  Multiplying by 1.25 does not make nice round numbers.  I'm also on 125% and also see some clipping in Edge, on the left.